# How to remove the HTML Special Character substitution when using "navigator.clipboard.writeText"

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I want to copy the Download Link from the screen:

```
var copyLink = document.getElementById("link").innerHTML;
navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyLink);
```

The correct link is:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/scl/fi/zlcgpjansfn0j2g7sfib8/huong_dan_giai_nen.txt?dl=0&rlkey=8ho01sbd6ua6713r7rv3jn1ua
```

Wrong link:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/scl/fi/zlcgpjansfn0j2g7sfib8/huong_dan_giai_nen.txt?dl=0&amp;rlkey=8ho01sbd6ua6713r7rv3jn1ua
```

But when I click Copy button to save to Clipboard and paste it, the `"&"` was replaced with `"&amp;"`
So the link is wrong

How does it keep the "&" sign?. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `innerText` instead.

```js
document.querySelector('#copy').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var copyLink = document.getElementById("link").innerText;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyLink);
})
```

```html
<div id="link">https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/scl/fi/zlcgpjansfn0j2g7sfib8/huong_dan_giai_nen.txt?dl=0&rlkey=8ho01sbd6ua6713r7rv3jn1ua</div>
<button id="copy">copy</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="paste link here" style="display: block;width: 100%;">
```